# A radio API for Android

Tags: android, fm-radio

Is there an API for developing applications that can play radio fm transmission frequencies?? I am developing an application that requires me to read FM signals and play radio channels. In other words there are Android radio applications. Just wonderring what API they used since there is no available API under the Android platform documentation. I will appreciate the help.Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559612/how-to-make-an-fm-radio-application-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970266/fm-radio-app-for-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official API for FM radio in Android, however enthusiasts found the way to enable radio on [Nexus One](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/07/13/nexus-one-finally-receives-fm-radio-support-not-thanks-to-google-but-the-android-community-coming-to-a-rom-near-you/)

Devices that I have seen so far have proprietary vendor-specific API to work with FM radio.

You can also use [this library](http://mmbtools.crc.ca/content/view/53/33/) to develop a FM Radio App for android. But this library is firmware dependent.

Another options would be to have an internet radio app, which streams the radio station from an online source.