# How to access android hardware radio

Tags: android, android-hardware

The main thing I need to do is to catch FM radio signal.

1. Is it possible to access to hardware radio directly?
2. Do I need rooted device?
3. Do I always need to use manufacturer drivers?

I've tried to use my integrated soft called "FM Radio", but it uses NDK, so I'm stuck there developing my app.

Answer (score 1):

It is not only very hard to do, it is also illegal in many cases. The RIL (Radio Interface Layer) is very thoroughly walled off from applications and has a very limited API that is not available to the public. In certain cases (I'm thinking of the TI Calypso) the specs and API have been leaked, but in general it is very difficult to access any radio functionality on a phone with an app.

Comment: ah, unfortunately it's a very similar answer. If you found something that works and the only problem is that you need the NDK, I would suggest using it since that's about 5 problems less than anything else :(

Comment: it also means your question is quite similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559612/how-to-make-an-fm-radio-application-in-android