# Is there an android API that can interact with radio functionality of mobile

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I have an android app idea that uses my mobile's radio. Currently, on my mobile, I only can listen to FM music on the radio which is a built-in feature but I want to figure out what can I do further for curiosity. I want to do android programming that interacts with device radio and do a specific task of my choice. Like when we want to interact with mobile cameras we use mediastore.camera and then we can capture images similarly I want to interact with device radio to experiment with different things on my mobile related to radio. But When I searched https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Radio, I could not find the code to interact with the mobile radio. All I found was MediaStore.Audio.Radio does not have sufficient methods to interact with device radio. then I searched on the internet and found that we need an API to interact with the device radio but that API is not built yet. How can I build such API? Do I really need to build such API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an FM Radio Application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559612/how-to-make-an-fm-radio-application-in-android)

Comment: I went through this answer before. It says there is no official api for radio in android. Then I wanted to know how can I build that api. could you please tell where can I build such api that interact with radio of mobile. Some api are built but they are only for nexus one or samsung (not for every device).

Comment: Learn about reverse engineering proprietary chipsets as each API would depend on the manufacturer (hint - takes a great deal of effort & low level domain knowledge). If you understand the [Audio HAL layer of AOSP that is a start](https://source.android.com/devices/audio). Good luck.